# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty on Celery worker run

Tags: python, django, celery

*Django version 1.9.7.*

My current project structure is:

```
vehicles/
├── etl
│   ├── etl
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── pipeline
│   └── bku
└── web
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── profiles
    ├── projects
    ├── reverse
    ├── static
    ├── templates
    ├── bku
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── admin.pyc
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── static
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── views.pyc
    └── rocket
        ├── celery.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings
        │   ├── base.py
        │   ├── dev.py
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── local.py
        │   ├── production.py
        │   ├── test.py
        ├── urls.py
        ├── wsgi.py
```

Now I want to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) in the `bku` Django app. But when I run the worker `celery -A rocket worker -l info` I get the following error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.`. I have the `SECRET_KEY` defined and I didn't have this error before trying Celery.

How can I run the worker?

*rocket/celery.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'rocket.settings')
app = Celery('rocket')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

*rocket/**init**.py*

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['bku']
```

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry you are right, the path to settings was wrong. I passed `rocket.settings.base` and now Celery works perfectly. Thank you. Post your answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading—usually when you see an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception like that it means that Django can't find your settings file.

In your case you're setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to `rocket.settings`, but from your directory structure it looks like it should instead be something like `rocket.settings.production`.